# How do i include the third parties Library (turn.js) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, page-flipping, turn.js

Right now , i need to do page flip animation in react . I saw turn.js library which is used for page flip . I imported that in the react component . It is not calling the Jquery function(.turn) in that library

Import statement

```
 import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'turn.js/index.js'
```

Oncomponent did mount method :

```
componentDidMount(){
    $("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoCenter: true
    });
}
```

On render :

```
 <div>
            <div ref="flipbook">
                <div className="hard"> Turn.js </div>
                <div className="hard"></div>
                <div> Page 1 </div>
                <div> Page 2 </div>
                <div> Page 3 </div>
                <div> Page 4 </div>
                <div className="hard"></div>
                <div className="hard"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Error in browsers console :

﻿

```
Turn.js?36f0:16 Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).turn is not a function
```

Comment: Then how can i use turn.js features in react ?

Comment: I am struggling with page bend when flipping.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use react-flip-page. Its good and also responsive.

Install it using npm:

```
npm install --save react-flip-page
```

Then you can use `FlipPage` as a component. Just like this:

```
<FlipPage>
  <article>
    <h1>My awesome first article</h1>
    <p>My awesome first content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>My wonderful second article</h1>
    <p>My wonderful second content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>My excellent third article</h1>
    <p>My excellent third content</p>
  </article>
</FlipPage>
```

[Here is the reference link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flip-page)